# Why is the い in 多い left out in 「本が多すぎる」?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, adjectives, compounds, compound-verbs

The translation I was going for was "(there's) too many books." I wrote 「本が多いすぎる」but autocorrect changed it to 「本が多すぎる」.

I then tried to use a na-adjective instead of an i-adjective, writing 「彼女は静かすぎる」"she's too quiet" and there is no な after 静か, so it looks to be the same pattern. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すぎる takes the stem of an I-adjective, Na-adjective.

The **stem of I-adjectives** are obtained by getting rid of い: 多い turns into simply 多

The **stem of Na-adjectives** are obtained by getting rid of な: 静かな turns into 静か.

You can read more about this on [How to use すぎる by MAGGIE SENSEI](https://maggiesensei.com/2018/03/02/how-to-use-%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B-sugiru/)